# which sentence is correct? "any simpler product than mugs" or "any product simpler than mugs"

Tags: sentence-construction

which one is correct?

> you can't create and sell **any simpler product than mugs**
>
> you can't create and sell **any product simpler than mugs**

Comment: Why do you think that one of them might not be correct?

Comment: Not an answer, but a mug is really quite complex:  you need quality ceramic clay, a molding/slip casting process, an image transfer and glazing process, probably two kiln firings. ...  I digress

Answer (score 1):

They are both fine and are used with relatively the same frequency, with alternating popularity going back at least 150 years

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=any+simpler+_NOUN_+than+_NOUN_%2Cany+_NOUN_+simpler+than+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cany%20simpler%20_NOUN_%20than%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20_NOUN_%20simpler%20than%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would have a slight preference for 'a' over 'any', but I wouldn't fight anyone to the death over it.